# Excel. Returning values from multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the spreadsheet below  showing figures for 3 products across various locations. I want to list the top 10 'lowest' figures via location. The SMALL function works at returning the values, but I can't figure out how to return the location and product details alongside the values.

Original Table
[image: Original]

```
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Location     | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Bristol      |    -10.2% |           |           |
| Bangkok      |    -30.5% |           |     -5.7% |
| Brighton     |     -4.7% |    -16.2% |           |
| Birmingham   |    -43.3% |    -13.8% |     -5.1% |
| Bath         |    -27.3% |     -6.9% |           |
| Bradford     |    -17.3% |    -25.9% |     -3.8% |
| Chelsea      |    -18.5% |    -13.2% |    -15.6% |
| Clevedon     |     -9.2% |     -6.3% |           |
| Durban       |    -42.5% |     -7.4% |           |
| Epsom        |    -12.9% |           |           |
| Exeter       |           |           |           |
| Glasgow      |           |           |           |
| High Wycombe |    -17.3% |           |    -47.2% |
| Leeds        |           |    -15.1% |           |

                             and so on
                                 ︙
```

Expected Results:

[image]

Comment: Once you have the value returned by `SMALL`, you should be able to do an `INDEX/MATCH` for the location

Comment: Index/Match doesn't work across multiple columns - that's the problem I'm having

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/8629780) to show us what the expected result would be

Comment: I tried. It says I must have a 10 reputation to post images

Comment: Post a link to a photo share site like imgur.com

Comment: I'll try and describe it. Show the output should show the Top 10 lowest values over 3 columns, as follows:                                         Waikiki   Product 1   -49.9%, High Wycombe   Product 3   -47.2%  etc

Comment: Are you not showing some data? How do you get a top 10 list per location, I only see a location listed once, and with only 3 products...?

Comment: A top 10 list by least value, showing the location, product & value (see above)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tMA5lbB    expected result image

Comment: It would really help if your sample data and expected output matched, Please take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It does match? I have tried using the index/match function but cannot get it to work across the columns. That is why I am asking for help

Comment: There is no Waikiki or Powys in your supplied data.

Comment: Apologies, I took a screenshot of the first few entries so people could get the idea. The whole table is here: https://imgur.com/a/Ii5cgZc

Comment: actually I did originally post the whole table, but somebody edited it!

Comment: You can get fancy and do a lookup for the SMALL result (e.g., with helper column), but that isn't reliable.  If the value appears more than once, it will return the first occurrence, which might not be the correct one.  I suspect this can be done with SUMPRODUCT or a fancy array formula.  But I haven't had nearly enough coffee to tackle it.  :-)

Comment: Actually, if you're doing it by location, it seems like you just need to return the column header for the minimum value in the row.  e.g., a helper column for the min value and a helper column for the associated column header.  Then focus on the location column and two helper columns, and use SMALL on those results to pick the lowest 10.

Comment: @ForwardEd Please don’t encourage people to post images of text.  I typed 60% of the OP’s spreadsheet; if you believed that the whole sheet needed to be in the question, you could have typed the last 40% yourself — or at least the rows for Waikiki and Powys.

Comment: @ScottCraner Please don’t encourage people to post images of text.

Comment: Updated answers : duplication considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**How it works:**

- To get top 10 values enter this Formula 
  in Cell `F181` & fill it down.

`=IF(ROW(A1)>10,"",SMALL(B$181:D$199,ROWS(F$2:F2)))`

- Formula in Cell `G181` to get related 
  Locations, also fill it down.

  `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$181:$A$199,MATCH(F181,B$181:B$199,0)),IFERROR(INDEX($A$181:$A$199,MATCH(F181,C$181:C$199,0)),IFERROR(INDEX($A$181:$A$199,MATCH(F181,D$181:D$199,0)),"")))`
- Final Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `H181`, 
  finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

  `{=INDEX(B$180:D$180,MAX(IF(B$181:D$199=F181,COLUMN(B$181:D$199)))-COLUMN(B181)+1)}`

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: This is great, many thanks!  Just one small problem is dealing with duplicate numbers - do you have a way of coping with this? (other than the rather inelegant method of just adding a percentage point!). Not a deal breaker, as this solves the problem well and I am very grateful.

Comment: @Alberto, is your objective to find the 10 cities with the lowest figures, or the cities for the 10 lowest figures?  For example, Waikiki contains two values that qualify in the top 10 if you are going by the values.  If you are going by cities, Waikiki would get in the list with 1st place, then there would be room in the list for another city.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Alberto,, glad to help you, yes while getting top values duplicate numbers can be ignored but in your case these numbers are related to specific Locations and Product ,, for example WaiKiki
should not considers as duplicate since has values with different products,, also since my solutions has solved the issue so you may accept it as Answer as well as Up vote also.

Comment: Clarification by Alberto posted as an answer: It is the cities for the 10 lowest figures that are needed (so it is quite possible a city will feature twice in the list).

Comment: @fixer1234,, yeah since location has value falling in more than one category .

Comment: @ fixer1234 good point.. "..list the top 10 'lowest' figures via location" is the OP request. Not product. I seem to agree that Wakiki is a dublicate from this point of view.. (Any comments @ Aberto? ) ||  @RajeshS great work on the array + index + match formula.. , However I could't reproduce your result..maybe coz your data set (19 items) is different that the OP(24 items)... I guess..

Comment: @p._phidot_ glad to help you ,,  keep asking☺

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer :

Riding on @fixer1234 comment.. I concur with the idea.. just need to add some special consideration for duplicated values.

Target: listing 10 cities.

Idea : get the lowest product X value from each city, sort city using that value, list the %, then city, then product number. For the duplicated town, the top name in the list will be shown 1st (you may put -49.90% in Product 2 Exeter to test this). The formulas uses indirect + offset + index + match excel function, no array is formula used.

Details :

Assuming the "Top 10 Concerns" Text is located at F1, and the "-10.2%" results is located at B2 (data is in A2:D25).

In F2 enter :

```
=IF(A2="","",IFERROR(SMALL(B2:D2,1),1))
```

and drag till F25, then in :

```
H2 ->  =H1+1
I2 ->  =SMALL(F:F,H2)
J2 ->  =INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&IF(I2=I1,MATCH(J1,A$2:A$25,0)+2,2),TRUE):A$25,MATCH(I2,INDIRECT("F"&IF(I2=I1,MATCH(J1,A$2:A$25,0)+2,2),TRUE):F$25,0))
K2 ->  =INDEX(B$1:D$1,MATCH(I2,OFFSET(B$1:D$1,MATCH(J2,A$2:A$25,0),0),0))
```

then drag 10 cells down. Done.

Hope it solves. ( :

---

Previous Answer (for archive purpose):

Assuming the "Top 10 Concerns" Text is located at F1, and the "-49.90%" results is located at H2. I'm also assuming that the Top10 results are unique. I'd propose, in F2, put :

```
=IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$A$25,MATCH(H2,$D$2:$D$25,0)),"")&IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$A$25,MATCH(H2,$C$2:$C$25,0)),"")&IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$A$25,MATCH(H2,$B$2:$B$25,0)),"")
```

Then in G2 :

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(H2,OFFSET($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$25,0),0),0))
```

and drag both downwards.

Idea : use index/match to get the location name, show null if "#N/A". Then 'load' Product 1/2/3 text by using double index match (with offset) in G2.

p/s : If there really is a tie.. (that I tried..) it fails.. so to improvise.. I just add 0.001% to one of the 'tie-ed' result (in column B,C,D) and the displayed values won't be affected. 
If you really do have a way to handle the tie differently, appreciate if you could  share it. ( :

Hope it helps.